# How to run an AVD with ext4?

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device, ext4

I want to run an AVD with ext4 in the android emulator. After creating a new AVD and running it, /system, /data and /cache are always mounted with yaffs2.

Is there a way to create an AVD with ext4?
or:
Can I change the file system after creating the AVD? It tried to simply remount it as ext4, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: This may help: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-building/mBn_A8AzJlw

Comment: What Android OS version are you trying? I would have expected Android 3.0+ emulators to use ext4.

Comment: @Kezz101 I also found the link you posted. How do you build an ext4 image manually? Do you just copy the /system in yaffs2, change it to ext4, copy it back to the AVD and mount it? Or can you use the /system from a real android device?

Comment: @CommonsWare Nope, it's always ext4, no matter the OS version.

Comment: @TimSmith I'm not sure I'm afraid. I just found that link and thought it would be helpful :/